# can`t connect to SQL Server DB with new user using Ubuntu VS Code extension - "SQL Server (mssql)"

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

have a server with DB on it that is runs on MS SQL Server. Admin created for me an user, but VS Code extension responds like in picture as shown below.
Have try with other user, no luck same error.
My typing attempts example:

1. F1 select the MS SQL:Connect - extencion
2. 192.168.789.321
3. database-name
4. username
5. paS$word
6. naming my connection
7. error as shown below

[image]

thank you!

Comment: Does your SQL Server support TLS 1.2? What version and edition of SQL Server is it?

Comment: At the moment i am at home, and they just gave me the login, pass and ip address that is all i have. I` ve asked is there any ssl or some type of a key? They said there is no keys.

Comment: The `SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol` portion of the error message suggests that the SQL Server is an older version that only supports TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 connections. Modern OpenSSL configurations require at least TLS 1.2 connections by default. You can usually alter the OpenSSL configuration files to support older, less secure, versions of TLS but you should really be pushing the SQL Server administrators to upgrade to a modern, supported version of SQL Server. Even unsupported versions of SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 can be configured to use TLS 1.2.

Comment: have add changes to MS SQL Server Extension on VSCode file: settings.json "trustServerCertificate": "true".

Now it says: "mssql: Connection error : A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)"

Comment: Thank you for respond. Have now connected to MS SQL Database with installing on my Ubuntu OS DBeaver app. It can handle old TLS connections, and have old driver that also was also casing problem no connection SQL Server JTDS Driver 1.3 version.